# XNA Advanced font rendering (outline, shadows, etc)

Tags: xna, outline

I am looking for a tool that will output spritefonts for XNA consumption that have an outline effect. I know that this can be done by rendering the text multiple times, but I'd like to take care of it in the content pipeline.

The options that I was able to find reference to were hosted at sites that are now offline. I know Nuclex has a vector font option, but again, I'd like to stick with sprite fonts and handle the rendering at compile time.

If anyone can link to an archived copy of those free tools, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I did some research on this and concluded that rendering text multiple times is the only/best way to do it. It's pretty performant, too, if it's in a single spritebatch. And it looks awesome.

Comment: I have no idea how XNA works but if you can use Signed Distance Fields somehow they will do the job

Comment: The best thing to do (unless you need the effect to be dynamic) is to use a sprite texture and just edit the image directly. See http://www.dylanwilson.net/bmfont-rendering-with-monogame-extended.

Answer (score 0):

Not shure about tool but I think you can do it using custom shader. For example, draw text to render target, then draw it again, but set outline color for pixels it is near letter pixel. Also you can use bitmap fonts and stylize it as you wish.